# From maya to c++ and opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, maya

I want to load an object created with Maya in c++ with opengl, how could I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Maya creates objects in a proprietary file format, and the approach to convert these objects in a way that can be read in C++ is very open-ended and left for the user to decide.

Since you don't give much detail, I think using the [ASSIMP library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) is the most straightforward solution. Maya supports export to OBJ (and I think 3DS, I'm not sure though), which this library can use.

Comment: I don't think it does 3DS, but I do know for a fact that it does .fbx, which I also know for a fact that 3Ds max could open.